git diff tab completion of tags hides file name completion (using bash)
I am using git on Ubunto with bash shell, and a tab-completion using bind '"\t":menu-complete' in my .bashrc file. When I do git diff X, tab-completion starts cycling with matching git tags, instead of matching files. If I complete enough characters such that no tags match, only then does the file-name completion works. How can I make git match both tags and files? Or, disable tag-matching temporarilty?

If you type
git diff --

before starting to enter file names, tab-completion should only consider files.
